# normalizer of a p-Sylow on $S_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $P$ be a group of order p, on $S_p$ , How can I prove that the cardinality of normalizer of $P$ it's $p(p-1)$ ?

If I compute that the number of conjugates of the group P, it's $
\frac{{n!}}
{{p\left( {p - 1} \right)}}
$ then I'm done, since equals to the index of the normalizer. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to calculate the normalizer directly.  Since all subgroups of order $p$ are conjugate in $S_p$ (they are all Sylow $p$-subgroups), we can take the subgroup $H$ generated by $(123\ldots p)$.  If we conjugate that generator by $\sigma \in S_p$, we get $(\sigma(1) \sigma(2) \ldots \sigma(p))$.  Now how many ways can we choose $\sigma$ so that cycle is still in $H$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's compute how many elements of order $p$ exists in $S_p$. It is exactly the number of $p$ cycles, which is $(p−1)!$. Let $n$ be the number of $p$ subgroups of $S_p$. We have $n(p-1)=(p−1)!$ because every element of a $p$-subgroup has order $p$ and every two nontrivial elements from two different $p$-subgroups are different. So $n=(p-2)!$ and these $n$ subgroups are Sylow $p $-subgroups. Since $n=|S_p|/|N(H)|$ by Sylow's theorem, $|N(H)|=p(p−1)$.